# Display my screen content to other device remotely

Tags: android

I am capturing my screen content using this

`MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();`

All screenshots are stored in the folder of my app. Now I want to share those all to another android device.

like team viewer or Skype.

Comment: Have look [this](https://github.com/Temasys/skylink-android-screen-sharing)

Comment: it will shows in own app i want in other device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a server for that. Upload all the photos to the server, and the other devices can download the photos from there.
Sending huge screenshots takes time, and for some users cost money.
What TeamViewer and Skype does is:

- Use heavy compression (Like JPeg200 or other wavelet compression)
- Only store the changes from one screenshot to another or divide the screen into blocks (like 200x200 pixels) and only send the blocks that changed since last screenshot.

There are many ways to this. You can usse this code sample as a reference:
https://github.com/Temasys/skylink-android-screen-sharing

Comment: Yes you are right and this github link is only useful inside app only.Thanks.

Comment: You could simply upload the images, like one every 5 seconds to a web server and have a simple html page that reloads the image. On another phone you can open the web site in the browser (doesn't even have to be android). But the update rate will not be fast as remote desktop, team viewer or the like.